# GWT Error Popup

Tags: gwt, popup, window

The error popup with the following error message comes on the screen repeatedly when application is in idle state (no user activity is performed).

```
Error occurred on client: (TypeError): Unable to get property 'iterator_0' of undefined or null reference. 

number: -2146823281
at handleEvent_206....EF34544...cache.html
at dispatchEvent_0..EF34544...cache.html
at sucess_184 ..
..
```

Can anyone give some pointers to navigate to the problamatic area in the code?

Comment: Are you in production or (super) dev mode? Open debug console in the browser to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're getting it repeatedly is probably due to the fact that you're performing an action on a timer (i.e. perform repeatedly an action).

From the small snippet you've shown, I don't think there's anything we can deduce. Do you have a larger stacktrace? It is still possible the error is in your own code (trying to invoke `iterator()` on a null object).